# How can I rectify from Error: flag needs an argument: 'c' in -c?

Tags: ubuntu, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, chaincode

I used the following command to initialise the chaincode after committing it to the hyperledger fabric test network.

```
peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C testchannel -n property --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles $CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE_ORG1 --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles $CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE_ORG2 --isInit -c `{"Args":[]}`
```

Then I encountered with the following error,

```
{Args:[]}: command not found
Error: flag needs an argument: 'c' in -c
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNoGG.png)

How can I rectify this error.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about this as I don't generally use the --isInit flag, but I believe that if it is used, you need to have an Init function in your contract to match the expectation of this flag i.e. it should have a method signature to suit what use of the flag expects to find.

I tend not to use the flag and instead, call a home grown Init function, as shown below.

```
-c '{"function":"initLedger","Args":[]}'
```

Have a look at this [link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/peerchaincode.html#peer-chaincode-invoke) if you haven't already.